# Объединить 2 массива в один (как в SQL, но силами PHP)?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива: один собирается из запроса к БД, другой - ответ от ядра через ZeroMQ. Вот они:

**1.**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["title"]=>
    string(25) "Numer One"
    ["enabled"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["source"]=>
    string(71) "rtsp://..."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["title"]=>
    string(27) "Number Two"
    ["enabled"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["source"]=>
    string(87) "rtsp://..."
  }
}
```

**2.**

```
array(2) {
  [6139]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [6140]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Значения во втором массиве - id, ключи - PID. 
Что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["pid"]=>
    string(4) "6139"
    ["title"]=>
    string(25) "Numer One"
    ["enabled"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["source"]=>
    string(71) "rtsp://..."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["pid"]=>
    string(4) "6140"
    ["title"]=>
    string(27) "Number Two"
    ["enabled"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["source"]=>
    string(87) "rtsp://..."
  }
}
```

P.S. Прекрасно знаю, как реализовать силами SQL, но как сделать в PHP - ума не приложу:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, все значения во втором массиве уникальны, поэтому для упрощения процесса перевернем его

```
$ar2 = array_flip($ar2);
foreach($ar1 as &$i) {
   // Если во втором массиве есть элемент с соответствующим id
   if (isset($ar2[$i['id']])) {
      // Добавляем его в первый массив
      $i['pid'] = $ar2[$i['id']];
   }
}
print_r($ar1);
```

**[demo](https://eval.in/608866)**

Comment: Да, PIDы, конечно же, уникальны. Перевернуть в ядре не могу - там полдня ковыряться...

Comment: так array_flip и перевернет

Comment: Ну это понятно, просто я объяснил, почему пришлось костыль в виде переворачивания использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$sql = array(
        array(
          "id" => "1",
          "title" => "Numer One",
          "enabled" => "1",
          "source" => "rtsp://..."
        ),
        array(
          "id" => "2",
          "title" => "Number Two",
          "enabled" => "1",
          "source" => "rtsp://..."
        )
      );
$json = array(
  6139 => "1",
  6140 => "2"
);

foreach($sql as $key => $arr) {
  $sql[$key]['pid'] = array_search($sql[$key]['id'], $json);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sql);
```

Comment: так гораздо медленнее, чем проверять ключ и непонятно, нужно ли pid => null, если id нет во втором массиве

Comment: @splash58 гораздо медленнее в массиве из двух значений? Что-то мне подсказывает, что на таких объемах, скорость у всех решений будет одинаковой. Десятки и сотни тысяч элементов в массиве в вопросе не заявлены.

Comment: я понимаю, что это философский вопрос, но пишем-то на общий случай :)  А то можно и так $sql[1]['pid'] =  6139; :)

Comment: На общий - да, медленно будет. А для моего апи, где задержка от ядра больше секунды сойдет. Теперь вот не знаю, отмечать как решение?

Comment: @GrigoryE. Зеленоград  ! А вы откуда, если не секрет?

Comment: @splash58, не секрет:) Из Крюково, 20 микрорайон.

Comment: @GrigoryE. :) я имел в виду про работу

Comment: @splash58, оу, еще учусь :)

Comment: Понятно, успехов!

Answer (score 0):

в дополнение к другим ответам, советую вам сходить по этой [ссылке](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Join_algorithms)  и посмотреть на алгоритмы джойнов.

мне приходилось разрабатывать джойны в php с разных серверов, и в принципе, врагу не посоветую делать это в php и, тем более, делать это в php с горой данных. Для моего конкретного случая (джойн с разных серверов), кстати,  наименее безкостыльным был вариант создания временной таблицы (temporary table) на сервере А, заливки в нее данных с сервера Б, джойна c temporary на сервере А и возвратом данных в приложение. (это было давно и не удивлюсь, если уже есть продвинутые решения для подобных случаев).

Кроме того, не удивлюсь, если быстрее для вас окажется заливать данные с ZMQ в бд и джойнить там. Совсем не удивлюсь.